# Hashbased data dedeuplication

Tags: java, deduplication

I am working on a project where I will get the data from the user's input form (no file processing). To avoid the duplication, I want to use either (fixed-length or fixed block) or (Variable length or Variable block).

- Which one is the better approach for the user's input data from small
  length (one liner) to big length (something like blog) ?
- I am looking in to md5 (fixed length) or sha1 (variable length), are there any better implementations for it?

Comment: "What is preferred" / "Which one is the better" are usually of topic, you might want to rephrase

Answer (score 0):

MD5 and Sha1 both are good for your application, both are collision resistant, and should work fine.